# OWASP HTML Sanitizer cleans comments

Tags: java, html, xss, owasp, html-sanitizing

I have application where customer can store following html lines in order to load different styles for actual browser:

```
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="default/css/general_ie6.css"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="default/css/general_ie7.css"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="default/css/general_ie8.css"><![endif]-->
```

Also I've configured `OWASP policy` to disallow malicious html tags in following way:

```
new HtmlPolicyBuilder().allowElements("link").allowAttributes("rel", "type", "media", "href").onElements("link").toFactory();
```

But after sanitation `if browser lines` are dropped.

Could you please suggest how to configure policy in order to allow storing such content?

Answer (score 2):

The OWASP Sanitizer can not be configured to accept these tags. Instead you could use a HTML parser like JSoup to extract these lines before santizing, then add them back in afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Issue #1532: Allow comments to be preserved in HTML](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/issues/152). Until that feature request, or a similar one, is completed, this is not possible with the HTML sanitizer.